# My simple Selenium program is not running?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm creating a simple program with `Selenium`. It runs into Java. Let me clear the first that I'm a beginner in `Selenium`.

So, my simple program for suggestion in google, Here you go:

```
package foo;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class GoogleSuggest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // The Firefox driver supports javascript 
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        // Go to the Google Suggest home page
        driver.get("http://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en");

        // Enter the query string "Cheese"
        WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        query.sendKeys("Cheese");

        // Sleep until the div we want is visible or 5 seconds is over
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000;
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
            WebElement resultsDiv = driver.findElement(By.className("gssb_e"));

            // If results have been returned, the results are displayed in a drop down.
            if (resultsDiv.isDisplayed()) {
              break;
            }
        }

        // And now list the suggestions
        List<WebElement> allSuggestions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@class='gssb_a gbqfsf']"));

        for (WebElement suggestion : allSuggestions) {
            System.out.println(suggestion.getText());
        }

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

After running this program, It opens an external `Firefox browser`. and give some error into my console program as:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"gssb_e"}
Command duration or timeout: 47 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'
System info: host: 'Rajendra', ip: '180.215.161.202', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=35.0, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 13e67b23-d0b6-493d-a936-5601591ee96f
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:352)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByClassName(RemoteWebDriver.java:433)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByClassName.findElement(By.java:387)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
    at foo.GoogleSuggest.main(GoogleSuggest.java:25)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"gssb_e"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'
System info: host: 'Rajendra', ip: '180.215.161.202', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///C:/Users/raj/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous1309276722675302219webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9641:26)
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement(file:///C:/Users/raj/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous1309276722675302219webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9650:3)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/raj/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous1309276722675302219webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11635:16)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/raj/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous1309276722675302219webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11640:7)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/raj/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous1309276722675302219webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11582:5)
```

*Help would be appreciated!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do following changes to your while loop code :

```
 while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
        WebElement resultsDiv = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfbw"));
        resultsDiv.click();

        // If results have been returned, the results are displayed in a drop down.
        if (resultsDiv.isDisplayed()) {
          break;
        }
    }
```

Your code not able to find search button because once it put query then page changes so.

Comment: Okay.. I changed it according to you.. But after running my program it shows new browser and after showing suggestions it disappears.. I think program gets `break`.. any idea?

Comment: Thanks.. Now it's running.. Can you please tell me.. Why it doesn't print that suggestion in console program? instead opening web browser?

Comment: Because it is getting ZERO value in your  allSuggestions variable. What do you want to achieve? want to get all link titles? which comes on page after search Cheese?

Comment: No.. look at this `Google search suggestion` program -> [Here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted) .. It says.. Suggestions would be printed into console program. But it opens external firefox browser? I don't understand.. What's happening here?

Comment: Yes.. This is what i'm saying .. It opens external browser.. But that program says.. Google suggestions will be printed into `Console program` through using `System.out.println();`. Do you have any links which provides the google suggestion tutorial?

Comment: See here , It finds all links from page. you can modify it by adding your sendkey to search : http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/11920/not-getting-all-links-from-page

Answer (score 0):

Ran in to the same issue as above of not being able to find the element.

However, on inspecting the HTML found out there was no id defined on the search button. Instead it had a name attribute defined as "btnG" as shown below.

```html
<button class="lsb" value="Search" aria-label="Google Search" name="btnG" type="submit"> <span class="sbico"></span> </button>
```

Adjusting the code within the while loop to the following, fixed the problem.

```
while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
            WebElement resultsDiv = driver.findElement(By.name("btnG"));
            resultsDiv.click();
```